# Reference a table by object_id in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I need a method of querying tables by their id instead of their name.

Using:

```
DECLARE @TableId AS INT = 1340567
```

I need an equivalent to the following example:

```
SELECT TableName.* FROM TableName WHERE TableName.Id BETWEEN 100 AND 199
```

Note: The TableName.Id is TableName's primary key.

I imagine it to look something like:

```
DECLARE @TableId AS INT = 1340567

SELECT GetTable(@TableId).* FROM GetTable(@TableId) WHERE GetTable(@TableId).Id BETWEEN 100 AND 199
```

But obviously, that doesn't work.

Note: I am aware that **object_ids change over time as SQL Server drops and recreates the tables internally**. It is out of interest only and I'm having difficulty finding information about it.

Comment: What happens if there are multiple tables with an ID between 100 and 199? If they have different table structures, you won't be able to get them back in 1 result set...

Comment: Simpler than that. The id is TableName's primary key. I used it for the sake of including a WHERE clause in the example.

Comment: What you are trying to achieve here?

Comment: @Kannan Kandasamy To reference a table by its object_id held in a variable instead of the name

Comment: you have already suggested in your question, but I feel it needs more emphasis: _this is a *really* bad idea_

Comment: @gvee There you go. I put it in bold and made an answer that says, "Don't do this!"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want to do requires dynamic SQL, something like this:

```
declare @sql nvarchar(max);

set @sql = 'select * from [table] where id between 100 and 199';

set @sql = replace(@sql, '[table]', quotename(object_name(@tableid)));

exec sp_executesql @sql;
```

Answer (score 0):

**Don't do this.**

This is a really bad idea since an object's Id will change over time as SQL Server drops and recreates tables internally.